# Bulk copy and rename several files in Bash, using underscores

Tags: bash

So, I have several files in bash in a directory called songs_old. I want to copy them to a folder called songs with a different name. Some names of the input files include:

```
unknownsong_song152.mid
town_song154.mid
nm_battle_song158.mid
fanfare_song159.mid
```

I want the results in "songs" to be like:

```
song152_unknownsong.mid
song154_town.mid
song158_nm_battle.mid
song159_fanfare.mid
```

I tried the following code to copy the files:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "./songs_old/"*".mid";do mkdir -p "./songs"
  cp "$i" "./songs/`basename "${i%.*}" | cut -d'_' -f2`_`basename "${i%.*}" | cut -d'_' -f1`.mid"
done
```

And my results were as follows:

```
song152_unknownsong.mid
song154_town.mid
battle_nm.mid
song159_fanfare.mid
```

How can I copy the files with the desired results?

Answer (score 2):

Using pure bash regex, you can do this:

```
cd songs_old
mkdir -p ../songs

for f in *.mid; do
   [[ $f =~ ^(.+)_([^_]+)(\.[^.]+)$ ]] &&
      cp "$f" ../songs/"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

This will run following `cp` commands for given sample:

```
cp unknownsong_song152.mid ../songs/song152_unknownsong.mid
cp town_song154.mid ../songs/song154_town.mid
cp nm_battle_song158.mid ../songs/song158_nm_battle.mid
cp fanfare_song159.mid ../songs/song159_fanfare.mid
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `cp` command is being piped to `cut` - that's the problem. You can rewrite the loop this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p songs
cd songs_old
for i in *.mid; do
  [[ -f "$i" ]] || continue # make sure we have a file
  new_file=$(sed -E 's/^(.*)_(song[0-9]+).mid$/\2_\1.mid/' <<< "$i")
  echo "Copying $i to $new_file"
  cp "$i" "../songs/$new_file"
done
```

- makes more sense to create the "songs" directory just once
- by cd'ing to songs_old and globbing, we eliminate the need for `basename`
- use `sed` and a regex to create the new name
- use relative path `../songs` while copying

For your set of files, it gives this output:

```
Copying fanfare_song159.mid to song159_fanfare.mid
Copying nm_battle_song158.mid to song158_nm_battle.mid
Copying town_song154.mid to song154_town.mid
Copying unknownsong_song152.mid to song152_unknownsong.mid
```